# Специализация шаблона вложенной структуры внутри внешней

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14

http://ideone.com/Mhpw1y - такой код работает как надо:

```
struct a
{
    template <int i> struct b
    {
        typedef int t; 
    };
};

template <> struct a::b <1>
{
    typedef double t;
};

int main()
{
    a::b<0>::t x;
    a::b<1>::t y;

    return 0;
}
```

Но я хочу перенести специализацию `b` внутрь `a`. Как это сделать?

Следующие способы не работают:

- http://ideone.com/3MdjdF

  > ```
  > prog.cpp:8:12: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'struct a'
  >   template <> struct b <1>
  >             ^
  > ```

  ```
  struct a
  {
      template <int i> struct b
      {
          typedef int t; 
      };

      template <> struct b <1>
      {
          typedef double t;
      };
  };
  ```
- http://ideone.com/XBD2ga

  > ```
  > prog.cpp:8:9: error: too few template-parameter-lists
  >   struct b <1>
  >          ^
  > ```

  ```
  struct a
  {
      template <int i> struct b
      {
          typedef int t; 
      };

      struct b <1>
      {
          typedef double t;
      };
  };
  ```

PS: Связано с [этим вопросом](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/624037/178988).

Comment: Что-то связанное с пространствами имён. Если заменить `struct a` на `namespace a`, то работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно стандарту C++ (14.7.3 Explicit specialization)

> 2 **An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace**
>   enclosing the specialized template. An explicit specialization whose
>   declarator-id is not qualiﬁed shall be declared in the nearest
>   enclosing namespace of the template, or, if the namespace is inline
>   (7.3.1), any namespace from its enclosing namespace set. Such a
>   declaration may also be a deﬁnition. If the declaration is not a
>   deﬁnition, the specialization may be deﬁned later (7.3.1.2).

Comment: Хм.. Но почему?

Comment: Не плохо бы на русском все это видеть.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я думаю, чтобы отличать объявления членов класса от их специализаций. То есть явную специализацию уже можно рассматривать как член класса, к которому может добавится другой член класса, полученный путем явной специализации первичного того же самого шаблона для другого аргумента.